# How to store multiple files in an array

Tags: split, csh

I am using the split command in cshell to split a file into smaller files. Since the split command names the output files xaa,xab,xac.... i have to rename them. I want to store the split commands output files in an array so it is easier for me to rename them. How would I go about doing this?

```
  set num = grep -c "$error" all_filtered_errors 

  if(num >= 1000000)

  split -l 100000 all_filtered_errors
```

Comment: Reading `man split` would be a good place to start. It has options to add a filename prefix, and a suffix, and to use numeric, hex, or character sequencing of sufficient length.

Comment: What system / `split` implementation is it? I don't know of a `split` that takes a `-c` option.

Comment: please don't post a picture of text ... post the text instead